# Is it a good practice to prevent an error?

Tags: vue.js

I am a beginner in vue.js 3.

Very often I have this error when a component is rendered :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'url_media' of undefined

To prevent that, I add a test for each of my var, like that :

```
 {{ classifiedAd.medias[0] ? classifiedAd.medias[0].url_media: null }}
```

It works, I have no more the error.

But is it a good pratice ? Is there any other method to prevent this kind of error ?

Comment: Is this value intentionally expected to be `undefined` at times?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. That an error occurs in the template results in rejected promise suggests that something is going on that you didn't show, likely Suspense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that `classifiedAd.medias` is always an array, a proper way to do this in Vue 2 is:

```
{{ classifiedAd.medias[0] ? classifiedAd.medias[0].url_media: null }}
```

or

```
{{ classifiedAd.medias[0] && classifiedAd.medias[0].url_media }}
```

Or computed property can make use of optional chaining:

```
classifiedAdMediaUrl() {
  return this.classifiedAd.medias[0]?.url_media
}
```

Vue 3 supports optional chaining in templates, so it can be:

```
{{ classifiedAd.medias[0]?.url_media }}
```

Computed property may still be preferable for readability.

This doesn't happen very often because a lot of times conditional HTML output is needed if some data is missing on purpose:

```
 <div v-if="classifiedAd.medias[0]">
 {{ classifiedAd.medias[0].url_media }}
</div>
<div v-else>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have difficulties with async functions.
`Uncaught (in promise)`
tells you that your used variables are undefined at that very moment your DOM gets rendered. it is a Uncaught promise.

to prevent this, you need to learn about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)